# Data copied from Textboxes to be displayed on Excel cell not display

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I'm trying to copy data from textboxes and set them on specific cells on Excel file In which have 2 sheets and sheet 1 named as "PM" and sheet 2 named as "4-10-2018" the process successfully done but on the second sheet not display data properly.
I checked my code many times but found nothing to fix this issue.

Code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlsht = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet();
        string path = @"D:\test.xlsx";
        xlsht = xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(path).Worksheets["PM"];
        xlsht.Cells[11, 2] = UserNameTxt.Text + "@rasatop.com";
        xlsht.Cells[11, 4] = UserNameTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[14, 2] = SerialTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[16, 2] = WLANMacTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[16, 3] = LANMacTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[16, 4] = IPTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[14, 5] = ComputerTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[16, 5] = BarcodeTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[18, 5] = CPUTxt.Text.Substring(0, 26);
        xlsht.Cells[18, 4] = VGATxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[18, 3] = RAMTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[27, 4] = OSTxt.Text;
        xlsht.Cells[5, 4] = System.DateTime.Today;
        xlsht.Cells[26, 4] = System.DateTime.Today;
        xlsht.Cells[9, 5] = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
        xlApp.Visible = true;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlsht2 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet();
        xlsht2 = xlApp.Application.Workbooks.Open(path).Worksheets["4-10-2018"];
        xlsht2.Cells[4, 2] = System.DateTime.Today;
        xlsht2.Cells[6, 2] = UserNameTxt.ToString();
        xlsht2.Cells[6, 4] = ComputerTxt.ToString();
        xlsht2.Cells[6, 5] = BarcodeTxt;
```

And after executing the code run successfully but data displayed as below in Screenshot:
Display Error:
[image: Display Error]

Answer (score 0):

In some places you are putting calling the .ToString() method of the TextBox control into your spreadsheet cell rather than reading its UserNameTxt.**Text** property which will contain the value.

Comment: Exactly! I don't know how did i miss this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem `UserNameTxt.ToString()`. You have to get`Text` property for TextBox value. Convert `UserNameTxt.ToString()`to `UserNameTxt.Text`

Comment: How couldn't See that! Thank you! you saved my day!